# Como separar un texto en c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

andaba haciendo un buscador para la importacion de un excel y me encontre con un problema  primero que anda el codigo que use como buscador es:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Nombres LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

en ese caso funciona puesto que el nombre de la columna en excel es "Nombres", pero me encontre con el problema de que el nombre de muchas de las Columnas poseen separacion por ejemplo una llamada "Banco Destino" y al usar el mismo metodo de buscador este no funciona:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Banco Destino LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text)
```

Ahora dicho excel no lo manipulo yo asi que no puedo cambiarle el nombre a la columna por esa deseaba saber cual es la forma que se utiliza en estos casos

Codigo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel;


namespace parque_beta_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        DataSet result;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Woorbook 97-2003|*.xls|Excel Woorbook|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    IExcelDataReader reader;
                    if (ofd.FilterIndex == 1)
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                    else
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
                    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    result = reader.AsDataSet();
                    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                    reader.Close();

                }
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = result.Tables[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Nombres LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Apellidos LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Banco Destino LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);

 }


            private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Imagenes:

[image: software al abrir]

[image: abrir archivo excel]

[image: Excel abierto con disponibilidad de vizualizacion de hojas]

[image: Hoja 1] (esta es la unica con nombres como column y un valor numerico)

[image: Hoja 2 con el buscador funcionando] En este caso el buscador funciona se uso el siguiente para que funcionara `(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Nombres LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);`

[image: Hoja 4]( esta posee titulos de columnas con separadas como "Banco Destino" Aca falla el buscador

[image: el error que señala] aca muestra al poner el codigo "Banco destino" solo toma Destino

La hoja 2 y 3 del excel son similares asi que no vi la necesidad de subirla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que no puedes crear nombres de columnas en excel con espacios? Podrias simplemente al momento de leer el nombre de la columna, cambiar los espacios por _ por ejemplo:

```
//Supongamos que header es el nombre de la columna
header.Replace(" ", "_");
```

De esa forma tienes resuelto el problema del espacio, ahora Banco Destino sera Banco_Destino

Edit:

Podrias probar tambien esto:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
 string.Format("[Nombre] LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
```

Encerra el corchetes el nombre de la columna

Comment: no entiendo donde podria poner eso, o probe hace poco y no me reconoce ni nada como header, pero si hay columnheader, tambien el hecho de que hay multiples nombres en las columnas del excel que tienen separaciones en sus nombres

Comment: Que es lo que exactamente queres hacer? Leer un excel o leer una grilla y crear un excel en base a esos datos?

Comment: mas que nada digamos logre importar un excel y este se mostraba en un datagridview pero en el contenido del excel habian titulos de columnas con separacio, y yo en el buscador de este andaba usando el modo mostrado para buscar el cual funcionaba , pero ahora por tener titulos separados lamentablemente no funciona, en el fondo es lograr hacer funcionar el buscador para los titulos del excel

Comment: Podrias agregar algo de codigo asi te puedo ayudar ?

Comment: puse el codigo del buscador que codigo te serviria? lo ponddre completo

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo y foto de un ejemplo con datos en el datagrid

Comment: fijate que ahi edite la respuesta, proba con eso

Comment: ```(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Nombres LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);``` en ese caso si funciona falla cuando son palabras separadas como titulo de columna de excel subire imagenes igual del programa importando las hojas de excel pero recotado ya que la info es privada

Comment: proba encerrando el nombre de la columna ente []

Comment: funciono hermano el [], muchas gracias

Comment: de nada, suerte!